# How to use file groups in SQL Server to speed up my database and optimization?

Tags: sql-server, performance, optimization, filegroup

How to use file groups in SQL Server to speed up my database and optimization ?

Please help me for create and use it .

Thanks .

Comment: Just using file groups doesn't guarantee any speed gain at all..... it only helps if you have the necessary hardware to actually support it - multiple disks (usually 5, 10 or more), multiple disk controllers - and you need to design your database system accordingly, too. Not an easy task. Not an easy "speed-up my app" switch at all ...

Answer (score 0):

to use filegroups you need to be sure that your disks volumes are physically separated, then you need to crate a file group, add an file to it and create partitioning function to distribute your table data into filegroups.